# C# Tool for refactoring call hierarchy to asynchronously wanted

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, resharper

I have a big call hierarchy like this.

```
//references 32
public int SomeMethod(string a)
{
    ...
    var s = MyMethod(a);
}

//references 43
public string MyMethod(string a)
{
    ...
}
```

I need to reimplement `MyMethod` to `MyMethodAsync` the question is how to do it "automatically". I'm looking for some tool/helper/plugin to Visual Studio or Resharper to help me as much as possible? Of course it can solve all problems, but I don't want waste few days on refactoring this. I don't have idea how many methods is in call hierarchy it can be few hundreds but also few thousands :-(

```
//references 32
public async Task<string> SomeMethodAsync(string a)
{
    ...
    var s = await MyMethodAsync(a);
}

//references 43
public async Task<string> MyMethodAsync(string a)
{
    ...
}
```

I tried https://github.com/BigBabay/AsyncConverter but it change only selected (one) method and update call to `var s = MyMethodAsync(a).Result;`

Comment: That is a bit of a tall ask, also you are basically asking for an offsite resource, which is one of the close reasons. We all had to do this at one stage with large code bases, its not really a hard thing to do manually if you are methodical about it

Comment: Async method usage differs from time to time, I'd suggest using converter you've mentioned, writing new code with ..Async calls, and slowly refactor old code, you can always find old code by searching for ".Result"